# Mysqli_query returning 0 rows (character problem?)

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a problem with this php code:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data['username']);
$password = md5($data['password']);
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM Utenti WHERE username = "$user" AND password = "$password"');
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    $status = 'ok';
} else{
    $status = 'error';
    session_destroy();
}
echo $status;?>
```

This is the request(json encoded):

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: example
User-Agent: example
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: length

data=%7B%22username%22%3A+%22harry%22%2C+%22password%22%3A+%22potter%22%7D
```

This returns 'error' bur when i write the query literally like this 'SELECT * FROM Utenti WHERE username = "harry" AND password = "potter"' it returns 'ok'. Furthermore the statement '$user == "harry" and $password == "potter" returns true. Could it be a character encoding/json problem?

p.s. I am aware of the security problems(md5, http) this is just a test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes in PHP mean the contents of the string are taken literally. So it will not insert the value of the `$user` and `$password` variables - it will literally be checking for the username `"$user"`.

You should enclose the entire query string in double quotes, then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you encapsulate your string (your SQL query) with single quotes, variables are not expanded. You need to use double quotes for that:

```
$string = 'user="$user"';
// literally the string: user="$user"

$string = "user=\"$user\"";
// literally the string: user="harry"
```

Comment: I didn't go into it in my answer because of your final comment, but using a prepared statement instead of a direct query with variables would have prevented this issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Change the select statement this way as you are using "$user" and "$password" inside the select statement enclosed with single quotes, the variables will be treated as literals. So you have to use double quotes for the statement and single quotes for the variables

```
"SELECT * FROM Utenti WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$password'"
```